# How can I place marginal notes always on the right but show normal odd/even headers?

Tags: header-footer, double-sided, marginpar

I would like to typeset a book where the odd/even pages have the same format: each has a long text section on the left and a place to put small marginal notes on the right. If necessary, I want the environments for tables/code in the text to be able to expand into this right margin.

But, I would like to get the standard odd/even page headers for chapters/sections.

Comment: Are you using a specific document class (please tell us what it is), or would you like suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes offer the class option `twoside=semi`:

- Left/right margins and positioning of marginal notes match that of `twoside=false` (`oneside` for the standard classes);
- Header/footer content/positioning match that of `twoside=true` (`twoside` for the standard classes).

---

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

Some text.\marginpar{First marginal note} \lipsum[1-6]

Some text.\marginpar{Second marginal note} \lipsum[7-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Koma-Script FTW :-)