# How can I add side-icons in a LaTeX book?

Tags: graphics, floats, book-design

Most of the technical books I've read use what I call "side icons" to mark out certain types of content. Stuff like "watch out for this" and "helpful tip", with corresponding icons.

Here's an example of what I mean (the "key point" and "coding horror" icons):

[image]

<sup>Taken from http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/on-the-meaning-of-coding-horror.html</sup>

How can I do this in LaTeX (with `\documentclass{book}`)? To be clear, I want to be able to attach icons (with captions) to text so that the icons are *outside* the normal flow of the text.

---

I have tried `\marginpar` (reversed), it's always pushing a portion of the image out of the paper. For example, the following code:

```
\reversemarginpar
\chapter{Getting started}
\pagestyle{headings}
AABBB
\marginpar{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/example}}

CCC
```

gives:

[image]

I get similar results with `\marginnote`

using http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg.

Comment: E.g. with `\marginpar` (LaTeX-kernel) or `\marginnote` (from the marginnote package).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Hmm, `\marginpar` doesn't work (see above). I'll try `\marginnote`

Comment: As seen in the first answer, this is more a problem of a page geometry than of a LaTeX solution. Because naturally, in a book, the inner margin is really small to contain any such material. However, if you use these "exclamation marks" often, you can make the inner margin wider, it wouldn't be that much a typographical crime ;)

Comment: `\marginpar` does work. But your page layout is not adapted for large objects on the inner margin. You can use `hfill` to move the picture on odd pages `\marginpar[{\hfill\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example}}]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example}}`. But if you want the pictures always on the left side, you should check this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62017/how-can-i-place-marginal-notes-always-on-the-right-but-show-normal-odd-even-head

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a right-justified paragraph:

```
\marginpar{\hfill\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/example}}
```

On even-numbered pages, you need a left-justified paragraph:

```
\marginpar{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/example}\hfill}
```

This can be simplified by using the optional argument for odd/even pages. It is convenient to encapsulate all this magic in a macro.

You may also need to adjust the size of the images to the width of the margin par:

```
\marginpar{\hfill\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{images/example}}
```

or use a fraction:

```
\marginpar{\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.95\marginparwidth]{images/example}}
```

Comment: This won't help with `\reversemarginpar`. `\marginparwidth` is larger than the left (inner) margin on odd pages.

Comment: Adding the appropriate `\hfill` worked for me.

Comment: You should use the optional argument for odd/even pages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try TikZ in 'overlay mode'. Maybe not elegant, but it works ;-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand{\keyPointR}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \node[draw, rectangle] at (13,0) {KeyPoint R};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\keyPointL}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \node[draw, rectangle] at (-8.5,0) {KeyPoint L};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\keyPointR

\blindtext[2]
\keyPointL

\blindtext
\end{document}`
```